# Error en paquete de instalacion de R,

Tags: r

Estoy Usando W10, y R 3.6.1 y tambien tengo R 4.0.2. En el cran dice que el paquete que necesito necesita R (≥ 3.5.0)
Estoy intentando inslar el paquete smdapp de las siguientes formas:

```
1. remotes::install_github("Abson-dev/sdmApp", dependencies = TRUE)

2. install.packages("sdmApp")
```

Y obtengo los sigueintes errores:

```
 1. Downloading GitHub repo Abson-dev/sdmApp@master
Skipping 31 packages not available: raster, sp, blockCV, CENFA, dismo, DT, kernlab, randomForest, readxl, rhandsontable, sf, shiny, shinyBS, shinyFiles, SSDM, ggcorrplot, ggplot2, cowplot, haven, dplyr, tidyr, data.table, rgeos, rJava, covr, knitr, rmarkdown, testthat, rgdal, automap, future.apply
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install Rtools custom from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
   
  checking for file 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEPQCBU\remotes5846f4a5ab\Abson-dev-sdmApp-9a1de3a/DESCRIPTION' ...
         checking for file 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEPQCBU\remotes5846f4a5ab\Abson-dev-sdmApp-9a1de3a/DESCRIPTION' ... 
      √  checking for file 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEPQCBU\remotes5846f4a5ab\Abson-dev-sdmApp-9a1de3a/DESCRIPTION' (1.5s)
      
  
-  preparing 'sdmApp': (969ms)
   checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
         checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
  
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
             
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (369ms)
                   -  checking for empty or unneeded directories
                
-  building 'sdmApp_0.0.2.tar.gz'
               
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependencies 'blockCV', 'CENFA', 'rhandsontable', 'shinyBS', 'shinyFiles', 'SSDM', 'ggcorrplot', 'cowplot' are not available for package 'sdmApp'
* removing 'C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/sdmApp'
Error: Failed to install 'sdmApp' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpEPQCBU/file58418aabe5/sdmApp_0.0.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
> library (sdmApp)
Error in library(sdmApp) : there is no package called ‘sdmApp’
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://nexus.uo.edu.cu:8081/repository/R-repository/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://nexus.uo.edu.cu:8081/repository/R-repository/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Error in install.packages(lib = .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) : 
  argument "pkgs" is missing, with no default
> 
> 
> install.packages("sdmApp")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://nexus.uo.edu.cu:8081/repository/R-repository/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://nexus.uo.edu.cu:8081/repository/R-repository/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://nexus.uo.edu.cu:8081/repository/R-repository/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'http://nexus.uo.edu.cu:8081/repository/R-repository/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘sdmApp’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

EL segundo error es este

```
2.Installing package into ‘C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mirror.epn.edu.ec/CRAN/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://mirror.epn.edu.ec/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mirror.epn.edu.ec/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
  cannot open URL 'https://mirror.epn.edu.ec/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
2: package ‘sdmAPP’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
```

A que se debe esto a un problema de configuracion o de conectividad de mi pc?

Comment: La clave está en el `ERROR: dependencies 'blockCV', 'CENFA', 'rhandsontable', 'shinyBS', 'shinyFiles', 'SSDM', 'ggcorrplot', 'cowplot' are not available for package 'sdmApp'`.Necesitas instalar esos paquetes primero

Comment: Y cuando mando a instalar un paquete las dependencias no se instalan de forma automáticas? O en todo caso preguntaria si deseo instalar las dependencias pero no lo hizo

Comment: depende de cómo está configurado el paquete. parece que en este caso te requiere que las instales manualmente

Comment: Pero instalar esas dependencias manualmente no requeriria , instalar esas dependencias q ellas necesitan seria una hostia eso !!!!!!!!!! madre mia

Comment: También menciona que necesitas instalar RTools , creo que seria el primer paso que tendrías que realizar

Comment: Coincido, me parece que hay alguna dependencia o el paquete que estás instalando propiamente dicho que tiene que instalarse desde código fuente. En Windows normalmente se instalan directo los binarios y no hace falta compilar, pero a veces no se puede. Como Windows no suele incluir las herramientas necesarias hace falta que instales Rtools a nivel sistema operativo. Otra dependencia complicada del paquete es rJava, que depende de una máquina virtual Java en tu sistema. Entiendo que en Windows puede ser complicada de poner a andar.

Comment: Una solución un poco radical y que podría tener sus propias complicaciones sería  instalar R para Linux usando el Windows Subsytem for Linux de W10. La ventaja es que ahí sí tendrías todas las herramientas de desarrollo disponibles y no hace falta Rtools y es mucho más fácil hacer andar rJava desde Linux. Si tienes alguna familiaridad con Ubuntu (más que nada usar `apt` para instalar librerías) sería una alternativa.

Comment: Rtools esta instalando y funcionando  y el rJava tambien hace tiempo los necesite para otro paquete y los puse ambos

Comment: Resuelto !!!! Era un problema con la conex del server de la universiad. Muchas gracias por todas las respuestas